# Reading function input values defined in `...` from an CSV file in R

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe, lapply

Suppose I have an R function like `foo` below. This function has 4 fixed arguments, and any number of arbitrary arguments defined in `...`.

All input values for `foo` arguments are stored in **[THIS](https://github.com/izeh/i/blob/master/j.csv)** CSV file.

In my code below, I can successfully run `foo` using the 4 fixed arguments imported from the CSV file in a `lapply` loop. **BUT** I'm wondering how I can insert the arguments defined in `...` in the `lapply` command?

```
foo <- function(n = NULL, r = NULL, post, control, ...){ ## the function

data.frame(n = n, r = r, post, control, ...)

}

D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/j.csv", h = T) # CSV file
L <- split(D, D$study.name) ; L[[1]] <- NULL

# the fixed args values:
      n <- lapply(1:length(L), function(i) L[[i]]$n)
      r <- lapply(1:length(L), function(i) L[[i]]$r)
   post <- lapply(1:length(L), function(i) L[[i]]$post)
control <- lapply(1:length(L), function(i) L[[i]]$control)

# names of args defined in `...`:
dot.names <- names(L[[1]])[!names(L[[1]]) %in% formalArgs(foo)][-1]

# the `...` args values:
a <- lapply(dot.names, function(i) lapply(L, function(j) j[grep(i, names(j))]))

## RUN `foo` function:
lapply(1:length(L), function(i) foo(n = n[[i]], r = r[[i]], post = post[[i]], 
                                     control = control[[i]])) # BUT! how can I insert the 
                                                              # arguments defined in `...` 
                                                              # in the function?
```

Comment: If you're using so many `lapply` calls, it might be time to write a function instead. `dots` are easier to work with within a function.

Comment: From the earlier post, have to make a slight change.  Please check the update for `base R`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can also use `Map` with `do.call`.  We can extract the arguments to the `foo` in a single call to `lapply` by extracting the columns 'n', 'r', 'post', control' and the extra columns (`...`) based on output of 'dot.names', then `transpose` (from `purrr` - or use the same approach as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705711/extracting-one-set-of-multiple-variables-in-a-list-of-data-frames-in-r/56705755?noredirect=1#comment99997847_56705755)) and pass it on `Map`

```
args <- lapply(L, function(x) unclass(x[c("n", "r", "post", "control", dot.names)]))
library(purrr)
unname(do.call(Map, c(f = foo, transpose(args))))
#[[1]]
#   n   r post control ESL prof scope type
#1 13 0.5    1   FALSE   1    2     0    1
#2 13 0.5    2   FALSE   1    2     0    1
#3 15 0.5    1   FALSE   1    2     0    1
#4 15 0.5    2   FALSE   1    2     0    1
#5 16 0.5    1    TRUE   1    2     0    1
#6 16 0.5    2    TRUE   1    2     0    1

#[[2]]
#   n   r post control ESL prof scope type
#1 13 0.5    1   FALSE   0    1     1    0
#2 13 0.5    2   FALSE   0    1     1    0
#3 15 0.5    1   FALSE   0    1     1    0
#4 15 0.5    2   FALSE   0    1     1    0
#5 16 0.5    1    TRUE   0    1     1    0
#6 16 0.5    2    TRUE   0    1     1    0

#[[3]]
#   n   r post control ESL prof scope type
#1 13 0.5    1   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#2 13 0.5    2   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#3 13 0.5    3   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#4 15 0.5    1   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#5 15 0.5    2   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#6 15 0.5    3   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#7 16 0.5    1    TRUE   1    3     0    1
#8 16 0.5    2    TRUE   1    3     0    1
#9 16 0.5    3    TRUE   1    3     0    1
```

The OP mentioned about replacing the `transpose` with a `base R` option

```
m1 <- simplify2array(lapply(names(args[[1]]), function(nm) 
     lapply(args, function(l1) l1[nm])))
do.call(Map, c(f = foo, unname(split(m1, col(m1)))))
```

---

Of if we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(L, ~ 
       .x %>%
           select(n, r, post, control, dot.names) %>% 
           as.list) %>% 
    transpose %>% 
    pmap(., foo)
#$Ellis.sh1
#   n   r post control ESL prof scope type
#1 13 0.5    1   FALSE   1    2     0    1
#2 13 0.5    2   FALSE   1    2     0    1
#3 15 0.5    1   FALSE   1    2     0    1
#4 15 0.5    2   FALSE   1    2     0    1
#5 16 0.5    1    TRUE   1    2     0    1
#6 16 0.5    2    TRUE   1    2     0    1

#$Goey1
#   n   r post control ESL prof scope type
#1 13 0.5    1   FALSE   0    1     1    0
#2 13 0.5    2   FALSE   0    1     1    0
#3 15 0.5    1   FALSE   0    1     1    0
#4 15 0.5    2   FALSE   0    1     1    0
#5 16 0.5    1    TRUE   0    1     1    0
#6 16 0.5    2    TRUE   0    1     1    0

#$kabla
#   n   r post control ESL prof scope type
#1 13 0.5    1   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#2 13 0.5    2   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#3 13 0.5    3   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#4 15 0.5    1   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#5 15 0.5    2   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#6 15 0.5    3   FALSE   1    3     0    1
#7 16 0.5    1    TRUE   1    3     0    1
#8 16 0.5    2    TRUE   1    3     0    1
#9 16 0.5    3    TRUE   1    3     0    1
```

#### Update

Based on the example showed [here](https://github.com/izeh/i/blob/master/R.r), the structure is slightly different, so we can transpose the `list` with `names` (for `base R`)

```
argsT <- setNames(lapply(names(args[[1]]), 
      function(nm) lapply(args, `[[`, nm)), names(args[[1]]))


out1 <- unname(do.call(Map, c(f = d.prepos, argsT)))
out2 <- unname(do.call(Map, c(f = d.prepos, purrr::transpose(args))))
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: rnorouzian's function in [**THIS DATA**](https://github.com/izeh/i/blob/master/R.r) is `d.prepos`. And his code is this:   `D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/k.csv", h = T)
; m <- split(D, D$study.name) ; m[[1]] <- NULL; ar <- formalArgs(d.prepos);  dot.names <- names(m[[1]])[!names(m[[1]]) %in% ar]; args <- lapply(m, function(x) unclass(x[c(head(ar, -1), dot.names)]));
  
  argsT <- setNames(lapply(names(args[[1]]), 
           function(i) lapply(args, `[[`, i)), names(args[[1]]));
  
do.call(Map, c(f = d.prepos, argsT))`

Comment: sure, no problem.

Comment: could you please paste here your complete solution?

Comment: @Reza I find it very confusing.  Can you please ask as a new question

Comment: My question is [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798225/keeping-the-original-order-of-data-after-split-in-r).

Answer (score 4):

Use `mapply` for this type of problem.
In the code below I have changed the way you define `n`, `r`, `post` and `control`.

```
n <- lapply(L, `[[`, 'n')
r <- lapply(L, `[[`, 'r')
post <- lapply(L, `[[`, 'post')
control <- lapply(L, `[[`, 'control')
```

The only difference is that these results have their `names` attribute set.

Then also change the way the list of lists `a` is created. Swap the two cycles.

```
a <- lapply(L, function(i) lapply(dot.names, function(k) i[grep(k, names(i))]))
```

Now the solution to the problem. It is mandatory to set `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`, the default `TRUE` gives a really bad output.

```
mapply(FUN = foo, n, r, post, control, a, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```