# keeping the original order of data after split() in R

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, split

In the following R code, I `split` a `data.frame` by a column, a string variable called `study.name`.

But `split` *alphabetically* re-orders the original `data.frame`. In **BASE R,** is it possible to keep the original order of data after splitting?

```
D <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/izeh/i/master/k.csv", h = T) # data.frame 
m <- split(D, D$study.name)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can `split` by `factor` converted 'study.name', where the `levels` are specified as the `unique` elements of the column and `unique` returns the values in the same order of occurrence of unique elements

```
split(D, factor(D$study.name, levels = unique(D$study.name)))
```

---

if we need to delete the `NA` elements, subset the data before the `split`

```
D1 <- subset(D, !(is.na(study.name)| study.name == ""))
split(D1, factor(D1$study.name, levels = unique(D1$study.name)))
#$Shin.Ellis
#  study.name group.name  n mpre mpos sdpre sdpos   r autoreg  t sdif F1 sdp df2 post control outcome ESL prof scope type
#1 Shin.Ellis   ME.short 13 0.34 0.72  0.37  0.34 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    1   FALSE       1   1    2     1    2
#2 Shin.Ellis    ME.long 13 0.34 0.39  0.37  0.36 0.5    TRUE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    2   FALSE       1   1    2     1    2
#3 Shin.Ellis  DCF.Short 15 0.37 0.54  0.38  0.36 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    1   FALSE       1   1    2     1    2
#4 Shin.Ellis   DCF.Long 15 0.37 0.49  0.38  0.36 0.5    TRUE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    2   FALSE       1   1    2     1    2
#5 Shin.Ellis Cont.Short 16 0.32 0.28  0.37  0.36 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    1    TRUE       1   1    2     1    2
#6 Shin.Ellis  Cont.Long 16 0.32 0.35  0.37  0.32 0.5    TRUE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    2    TRUE       1   1    2     1    2

#$Trus.Hsu
#  study.name group.name  n   mpre   mpos  sdpre  sdpos   r autoreg  t sdif F1 sdp df2 post control outcome ESL prof scope type
#8   Trus.Hsu      Exper 21 0.0799 0.1130 0.0367 0.0472 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    1   FALSE       1   2    2     2    1
#9   Trus.Hsu       Cont 26 0.0763 0.1095 0.0389 0.0537 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    1    TRUE       1   2    2     2    1

#$kabla
#   study.name group.name  n mpre mpos sdpre sdpos   r autoreg  t sdif F1 sdp df2 post control outcome ESL prof scope type
#11      kabla   ME.short 13 0.34 0.72  0.37  0.34 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    1   FALSE       1   1    3     0    1
#12      kabla    ME.long 13 0.34 0.39  0.37  0.36 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    2   FALSE       1   1    3     0    1
#13      kabla  DCF.Short 15 0.37 0.54  0.38  0.36 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    1   FALSE       1   1    3     0    1
#14      kabla   DCF.Long 15 0.37 0.49  0.38  0.36 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    2   FALSE       1   1    3     0    1
#15      kabla Cont.Short 16 0.32 0.28  0.37  0.36 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    1    TRUE       1   1    3     0    1
#16      kabla  Cont.Long 16 0.32 0.35  0.37  0.32 0.5   FALSE NA   NA NA  NA  NA    2    TRUE       1   1    3     0    1
```

Comment: Maybe Arun you like [**THIS QUESTION**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810292/extracting-the-names-of-a-list-of-data-frames-along-with-values-in-the-data-fram)?