# Extracting the names of a list of data.frames along with values in the data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, dataframe

In below code, `j` is a named list of data.frames. I was wondering if there might be a way to:

**(a)** extract the numeric values of the variables (i.e., `one.short` and `one.long`) inside the data.frames and attach their related names (i.e., `"AAA"` or `"BBB"` or `"CCC"`) to the extracted values?

**(b)** if a variable (i.e., `one.short` or `one.long`) is `NA`, then change the name of that data.frame to `NA` when extracting that variable?

**Expected output:**

In the below example, I expect my output to be like:

`one.short = list(c("AAA", .6), c(NA, NA), c("CCC", .4))`

`one.long = list(c("AAA", .8), c(NA, NA), c(NA, NA))`

**R Code and reproducible data:**

```
j <- list(data.frame(one.short = .6, one.long = .8), data.frame(one.short = NA, 
one.long = NA), data.frame(one.short = .4, one.long = NA))

names(j) <- c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")

# I tried this without success:
one.short = sapply(1:length(j), function(i) j[[i]]$one.short)
one.long  = sapply(1:length(j), function(i) j[[i]]$one.long)
```

Comment: you can iterate on `names(j)` directly and get the desired result, like this `sapply(names(j), function(x) j[[x]]$one.short)`

Comment: @Nate, but how to change the names of `NA` values to `NULL` or `NA`?

Comment: maybe just do it after the extraction, like this `sapply(names(j), function(x) j[[x]]$one.short) %>% setNames(ifelse(is.na(.), NA, names(.)))`? does that work? (didn't really read your whole question, tsk tsk)

Comment: Nate thank you so much, I appreciate that. I only use Base R, could you possibly provide a Base R solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `[[` to do this without anonymous function

```
v1 <- sapply(j, `[[`, 'one.short')
v1
#  AAA BBB CCC 
# 0.6  NA 0.4
```

If we want to set the names of values that NA

```
names(v1)[is.na(v1)] <- "NULL"
v1
#   AAA NULL  CCC 
#  0.6   NA  0.4
```

---

Note that `NULL`would need to be in a `list` because it gets dropped in a `vector`

```
c('a', 'b', NULL)
#[1] "a" "b"   


list('a', 'b', NULL)
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "b"

#[[3]]
#NULL
```

Comment: just be aware that is not `NULL` but a character string "NULL" `is.null(names(j_short))`

Comment: @Reza In that case you can use on the value itself `v2 <- v1[!is.na(v1)]`

Comment: Arun, if you wanted to use `v1 <- sapply(j, `[[`, 'variable.name')` and then `v2 <- v1[!is.na(v1)]` for several variables (not just `one.short` as in my question), what code would you use?

Comment: @Reza If you want to extract several, then `m1 <- sapply(j, `[`, c('one.short', 'one.long'))` and then it may be a matrix output.  which you may have to subset with `!is.na` and depending upon the NA elements in one or both, it may need to processed

Comment: @Reza I used backquotes, it is not showed, try `sapply(j, "[", c("one.short", "one.long"))`

Comment: @Reza The result would be a matrix., You may need to remove the  rows by creating a logical index with `rowSums` or `colSums` (depends on what you wanted)

Comment: @Reza Try `lapply(c('one.short', 'one.long'), function(nm) {v1 <- sapply(j, '[[', nm); v1[!is.na(v1)]})`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the base version, all you need is the intermediate assigment to make it work.

```
j_short <- sapply(names(j), function(x) j[[x]]$one.short)

j_short <- setNames(j_short, ifelse(is.na(j_short), NA, names(j_short)))

j_short
AAA BBB CCC 
0.6  NA 0.4
```